# Display JSON data with Node.js and Handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, nodes

I am learning Node.js and having trouble displaying user name with return json. Here's what I'm using:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const expressHbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride  = require('method-override');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const moment = require('moment');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');

// global variables
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    // res.locals.user = **req.user** || null;
    res.locals.user = **JSON.stringify(req.user)** || null;
    next();
});
```

list.hbs

On this page I dump the user object like so: `{{user}}`.

Tried `JSON.stringify(req.user)` and got the following output.

```
{"_id":"5a720ab7b09fed40ef0e0c96","uid":"3456","fname":"Brad","lname":"Jones","active":true,"accessLevel":3,"date":"2018-02-01T23:51:59.381Z"}
```

Tried `req.user` and got the following output.

```
{ _id: 5a720ab7b09fed40ef0e0c96, uid: '3456', fname: 'Brad', lname: 'Jones', active: true, accessLevel: 3, date: 2018-02-02T00:05:44.253Z }
```

I've try accessing the name like so but nothing works.

- `{{user.lname}}`
- `{{user['lname']}}`

This is interesting, in the list.hbs I'm able to output the fname via `each`.

```
{{#each user}}
    ({{fname}})
{{/each}}
```

Notice the '()' in the output below, it appears there are multiple `user.fname`.

```
() () () (Brad) ()
```

Why might this be?

### Update

Just tried this:

```
{{#each user}}
    ({{@index}} {{fname}})
{{/each}}

output this:
(0 ) (1 ) (2 ) (3 Brad) (4 )
```

Is there way to target the fourth value?

Comment: Did you simply try `{{lname}}` ?

Comment: Hi Gibin, thanks for your suggestion. Sadly it didn't work.

Comment: How about `req.user.lname`? May be I'm suggesting a blunder but just curious.

Comment: Tried {{req.user.fname}} too, no luck. The funny thing is a have a working identical site using ejs. I just prefer handlebars.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the model didn't not match the database columns.